# How to view messages/log files in kile?

Tags: kile

I am using text editor 'kile 2.1 beta 4' on the system 'ubuntu 10.04' . But in kile I can,t view the 'messages/log files' :
[image]

Here is an screenshot of my 'kile' is  given below :
[image]

How can I view 'messages/log files' ?

Comment: Did you try to click on that vertical buttons between the left scroll bar and the main window. See that there is above the alpha button another two, named *structure* and *files and projects*.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I noticed it was hidden in the bottom because its height was reduced a lot and there was nothing to show. I don't know the root cause but I fixed it as follows.
I went to the bottom of the `kile` and tracked the mouse cursor. At some point at the bottom of the `kile` window (approximately 1cm or quarter of an inch above the bottom) the cursor symbol changed to resize. It is above the `Line information`.
Use it to pull up the `Log and messages` window.

Answer (score 2):

On my version of Kile (2.1.3) you go

```
settings >> Show Messages Bar
```

The message bar then shows up on the bottom of the screen. It might be resized to be really small making it invisible. If so, there will be 3 really little dots that you can grab to resize it.